# Activity is overlapping fragment home

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm developing a Calorie app where the user can delete an item from the listview.

PROBLEM:  When the user clicks on the item it goes to the calorie details activity,when they click delete it goes back to the home fragment. As soon as I click on add another entry it crashes. Also when it goes back to fragment home  it doesnt look the same the calorie details activity is over lapping the fragment home not completely replacing it.

calorieDetails.java

```
       public class CalorieDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

 private TextView foodName, calories, dateTaken;
 private Button shareButton;
 private int foodId;
 private Button deleteButton;


 private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
 private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_calorie_details);

  foodName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detsFoodName);
  calories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detscaloriesValue);
  dateTaken = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detsDateText);

  deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

  Food food = (Food) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("userObj");

  foodName.setText(food.getFoodName());
  calories.setText(String.valueOf(food.getCalories()));
  dateTaken.setText(food.getRecordDate());


  foodId = food.getFoodId();
  foodName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  dateTaken.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  calories.setTextSize(34.9 f);
  calories.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

  deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     //TODO: put delete functionality here
     android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new
     android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(CalorieDetails.this);
     alert.setTitle("Delete?");
     alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
     alert.setNegativeButton("No", null);
     alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        DatabaseHandler dba = new
        DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        dba.deleteFood(foodId);

        Toast.makeText(CalorieDetails.this, "Food Item 
         Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         FragmentHome homeFragment = new FragmentHome();


         fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder,
          homeFragment); fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
       });

      alert.show();

     }
    });
  }
 }
```

FragmentHome.java

```
                public class FragmentHome extends Fragment implements
View.OnClickListener {

  private TextView caloriesTotal;
  private TextView caloriesRemain;
  private ListView listView;
  private LinearLayout mLayout;

  ImageButton AddEntrybtn;
  ImageButton ResetEntry;
  Context context;

  int goalCalories;
  int totalCalorie;

  Button mButton;

  //Database
  private DatabaseHandler dba;

  private ArrayList < Food > dbFoods = new ArrayList < > ();
  private CustomListViewAdapter foodAdapter;
  private Food myFood;

  //fragment
  private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
  private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

  public FragmentHome() {
   // Required empty public constructor
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
    false);

   caloriesTotal = (TextView)
   myView.findViewById(R.id.tv_calorie_amount);

   caloriesRemain = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.calorieRemain);

   listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ListId);

   SharedPreferences prefs =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
   PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(),
    R.xml.activity_preference, false);

   goalCalories =
    Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount",
     "2000"));

   AddEntrybtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.AddItems);

   AddEntrybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
     ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(4);
    }
   });

   ResetEntry = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.ResetEntry);
   ResetEntry.setOnClickListener(this);

   refreshData();

   return myView;
  }

  public void reset() {

   dbFoods.clear();

   dba = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

   ArrayList < Food > foodsFromDB = dba.getFoods();

   //Loop
   for (int i = 0; i < foodsFromDB.size(); i++) {

    String name = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodName();
    String date = foodsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
    int cal = foodsFromDB.get(i).getCalories();
    int foodId = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodId();

    Log.v("Food Id", String.valueOf(foodId));

    myFood = new Food();
    myFood.setFoodId(foodId);
    myFood.setFoodName(name);
    myFood.setCalories(cal);
    myFood.setRecordDate(date);

    dbFoods.clear();

    dbFoods.remove(myFood);
    foodsFromDB.remove(myFood);
    dba.deleteFood(foodId);
   }
   dba.close();

   //setting food Adapter:
   foodAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
    R.layout.row_item, dbFoods);
   listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
   foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  public void refreshData() {

   dbFoods.clear();

   dba = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

   ArrayList < Food > foodsFromDB = dba.getFoods();

   totalCalorie = dba.totalCalories();

   String formattedCalories = Utils.formatNumber(totalCalorie);
   String formattedRemain = Utils.formatNumber(goalCalories -
    totalCalorie);

   //setting the editTexts:

   caloriesTotal.setText("Total Calories: " + formattedCalories);

   caloriesRemain.setText(formattedRemain);

   SharedPreferences prefs =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
   PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(),
    R.xml.activity_preference, false);

   goalCalories =
    Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount", "2000"));

   //Loop
   for (int i = 0; i < foodsFromDB.size(); i++) {

    String name = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodName();
    String date = foodsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
    int cal = foodsFromDB.get(i).getCalories();
    int foodId = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodId();

    Log.v("Food Id", String.valueOf(foodId));

    myFood = new Food();
    myFood.setFoodId(foodId);
    myFood.setFoodName(name);
    myFood.setCalories(cal);
    myFood.setRecordDate(date);

    dbFoods.add(myFood);
   }
   dba.close();

   //setting food Adapter:
   foodAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
    R.layout.row_item, dbFoods);
   listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
   foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


  }

  //save prefs
  public void savePrefs(String key, int value) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
   }
   //get prefs
  public int loadPrefs(String key, int value) {
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
   return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, value);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   Bundle username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
   String username1 = username.getString("Username");
   TextView userMain = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.User);
   userMain.setText(username1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
   super.onDetach();
   startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class));
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.AddItems:

     AddEntry addEntry = new AddEntry();

     fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder, addEntry).commit();

     break;

    case R.id.action_settings:
     Intent preferenceScreenIntent = new Intent(getContext(),
      PreferenceScreenActivity.class);
     startActivity(preferenceScreenIntent);
     break;

    case R.id.ResetEntry:
     reset();
     break;
   }
  }
```

activity_calorie_details.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/FragmentHolder"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                tools:context=".CalorieDetails"
                android:background="@drawable/imgbackground2"
                style="@style/AppTheme">
    <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/logo"
               android:src="@drawable/weight"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp" />
    <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/layout"
             android:elevation="4dp"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detsFoodName"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:text="dkdad"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detsCaloriesTitle"
            android:text="Calories:"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detscaloriesValue"
            android:text="200"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detsDateText"
            android:text="Consumed on..."
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:text="DELETE"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Home_fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

              android:layout_width="match_parent"

              android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
               android:background="@drawable/imgbackground2"
                style="@style/AppTheme"

                  tools:context="layout.HomeFragment"
                   android:id="@+id/HomeFragment">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_height="271dp">
        <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Welcome,"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"

                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/emptyString"
                    android:id="@+id/User"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_main_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="24dp"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="@string/activity_text_calorie_title"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_calorie_amount"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    tools:text="1600"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_main_title"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="false" />
        <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/AddItems"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/add"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_calorie_amount"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <TextView
                tools:text="1600"
                android:id="@+id/calorieRemain"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_main_title"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ResetEntry"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@drawable/removecircle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/AddItems"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/AddItems" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="274dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">
        <ListView
              android:id="@+id/ListId"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:dividerHeight="2dp"
              android:divider="#212121"
              android:scrollingCache="false"
              android:smoothScrollbar="false"
              android:layout_below="@+id/tv_calorie_amount"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of what happens after clicking delete:

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c0939b3

Here is what the Home Fragment Looks like before deleting item:
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=70e433d

logcat when I click Delete on the Calorie Details fragment

```
      05-04 02:25:25.561 5830-5830/com.example.treycoco.calorietracker
      E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = 
     android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@14b764b

     05-04 02:25:25.571 5830-5830/com.example.treycoco.calorietracker
     E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = 
    com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@42e6828

    05-04 02:25:25.571 5830-5830/com.example.treycoco.calorietracker
    E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = 
    com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@42e6828


      05-04 02:25:25.581 5830-5830/com.example.treycoco.calorietracker 
     E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

When I click on Add Entry After Clicking on Delete
Logcat:

```
              05-04 02:28:04.761 5830-
              5830/com.example.treycoco.calorietracker E/AndroidRuntime:
              FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: com.example.treycoco.calorietracker, PID: 5830
           java.lang.ClassCastException
           com.example.treycoco.calorietracker.CalorieDetails cannot be cast
           to com.example.treycoco.calorietracker.appMain
           at com.example.treycoco.calorietracker.
           FragmentHome$1.onClick(FragmentHome.java:118)
          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
     (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: The logic that you created isn't quite clear. I guess that the best way to do what you want is using one activity with a list of "food" and handling the deletion in your adapter or recyclerview, then when you tap on an item you can attach a food fragment to your activity and see the calories. The overlapping problem is because you have set a different padding in the fragment and activity xml.

Comment: Whats the best way to fix this? Im currently new to android studio and this is for a class project which is due tomorrow :/ I"ve been trying to figure this out.

Comment: 1) Create your activity with the list of your food 2) create a recyclerview with all your items 3) create an activity content for your calories fragment 4) create your calories fragment. [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments) here you can find all what you need for the points 1) 3) 4). [link](http://android-er.blogspot.it/2015/07/add-and-remove-items-to-recyclerview.html) here for the point 2).

Comment: Thanks man I will take a look at this

Comment: Hopefully I can figure it out

Comment: Fragments are a pain in the butt

Comment: Right now I also have another button where they can clear the listview all together and that works. That is in my fragment home

Comment: Its just doing it individual that is giving me issues

Comment: Yes when you start with android dev, the fragments are not your best friends. Read the guides above!

Comment: Would there be an easier way just so that it wont overlap and crash or is this the only way

Comment: For the overlap remove the padding in the xml file, for the crash you have to rewrite the entire logic. Man are four classes that you have to rewrite from zero and they are very easy...

Comment: What if I changed the calorie details to a fragment would I still run into problems